# key word remap enter carriage return vim command line

Tags: command-line, vim, shortcut-keys

In my `.vimrc` file I have

```
:imap ii <CR>
```

which allows me to hit `ii` for enter/carriage return in vim

but now i would like to set that same configuration in my `.inputrc` so that i can just hit `ii` when i need to hit enter in command line.

This is my .inputrc config which is set to vi and also has an if that takes me into normal mode when i hit "sv"

```
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi
    # insert mode
    set keymap vi-insert
    "sv": vi-movement-mode # remap escape
$endif
```

I would prefer if I could map `ii` carriage return in normal and or insert mode in an if statement so that I can switch it back when I remove the vi editing mode.

thank you i have since figured it out
$if mode=vi
          set keymap vi-insert
          "uu": accept-line
  $endif

this allows me to use uu as my enter in my command line while using an if statement